# ignoring parent's onClick reactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

how can i ignore a father's onClick function and use only the child's onclick function (without using jQuery or angular)?

```html
<div onclick="alert('US')"> country
  <div onclick="alert('NY')">city</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In general, you shouldn't put `onClick` handlers on div elements. If it is something like a button, use a `<button>` element. There are many accessibility issues around putting click handlers on div elements. The exception to this would be adding a click handler to a dialog overlay to close it. But in that case, there should be a `<button>` element in the dialog that is also able to close the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Call `e.stopPropagation()` either inline or preferably in a function.

```
handleClick(e, text){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(text);
}

render(){
    return (
        <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'US')}> country
            <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'NY')}}>city</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to call stopPropagation on the event object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

This will stop the event being bubbled up to the parent's handlers as well.

Here it is working with your inline click handler, although I'd recommend you pull them out into functions to make them more readable!

```html
<div onclick="alert('US')"> country
  <div onclick="event.stopPropagation(); alert('NY');">city</div>
 </div>
```